# Java Package Compiling Issue

Tags: java

OK, like many of the package compiling issues out there I have not found one like this out of the 12 hours I've spent searching..

Basically I have the normal setup :

My Directories are as follows: JavaCSVReader/FRC_API

My Source files are setup as this:

```
JavaCSVReader/CSVFile.java
JavaCSVReader/FRC_API/RobotConfig.java
```

(that is `CSVFile.java` is located in `JavaCSVReader` and same for `RobotConfig.java`)

`CSVFile.java` contains the lines:

```
    package JavaCSVReader;
    import JavaCSVReader.FRC_API.*;
       ...
```

`RobotConfig.java` contains the lines:

```
    package JavaCSVReader.FRC_API;
    import JavaCSVReader.CSVFile;
        ...
```

Both files compile fine without the lines above.

The error is thus: I receive

```
"cannot find symbol... class: CSVFile location: JavaCSVReader"
```

when I try to compile the RobotConfig.java.

I also receive the

```
"package does not exist: JavaCSVReader.FRC_API" error when compiling CSVSFile.java
```

my

```
CLASSPATH=/home/src/JavaCSVReader/:.:..
```

(I am using linux)

Answer (score 4):

Your classpath setting is wrong. You should set it to

```
/home/src/
```

The compiler will take classpath as the "base" directory in order to find packages defined in the source.

Answer (score 0):

it's a classpath issue.
How do you configure java environment variables?
You'd better check on it.

Answer (score 0):

is your package JavaCSVReader.FRC_API; or JavaCSVReader ?

Comment: THe package is JavaCSVReader.FRC_API. The issue was the classpath. I was not sure on the meaning of the term base class.